# Is it possible to embed controllers with Play Framework?

Tags: playframework

I have two forms, each with their own actions. Then I have a page which is supposed to embed these two forms in a single page.

Is it possible to embed/include other actions in an action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what are you asking. If you want to include a form inside another form, HTML does not allow. You can pick a javascript based solution to simulate a embeded form or you can make the forms sibling and use absolute position to make it appear one inside another.

If you just want to add two templates in the same page, you can do that making them tags or using the render tag.

Comment: Nope, I'm not trying to stick a form inside another. I simply want two separate forms on the page, each will submit to a different action.

Comment: Then it's an HTML problem, and you have to chose to solve it with css or javascript, as i said.